# How to filter an array of objects by their first letter in react/javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am fairly new to React and javascript environment so some of the syntax and errors don't make sense to me. I have tried using the filter function something like this but gives me an error of *undefined is not an object.*

```
const temp = example.filter(x => x.includes('A'))
```

**Example:**

```
data = [{id: 1, type: Pizza}, {id: 2, type: Taco}, {id: 3, type: Pasta}, {id: 4, type: Sandwich}, {id: 5, type: Pumpkin Pie}]
```

**Output:**

```
temp = [{id: 1, type: Pizza}, {id: 3, type: Pasta}, {id: 5, type: Pumpkin Pie}]
```

Comment: Hi, please format your code a bit better. :)

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `startWith`:

```js
let data = [{id: 1, type: 'Pizza'}, {id: 2, type: 'Taco'}, {id: 3, type: 'Pasta'}, {id: 4, type: 'Sandwich'}, {id: 5, type: 'Pumpkin Pie'}]

// Output:

let result = data.filter(f => f.type.toLowerCase().startsWith('p'))
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Would `type[0]` not be more simple in this case? Hmm, although yours seems more readable.

Comment: Even when I do this, I get such error "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'f.CRS_SUBJ_CD.toLowerCase')". Not understanding what that means.

Comment: Could you show what `f` and `CRS_SUBJ_CD` variables are?

Comment: @La in my view, when `startsWith` is used, then it is more flexible to set searched string. E.g., `.startsWith('Pi')` or any another string

Comment: @ShalinPatel try to write with brackets `f.CRS_SUBJ_CD.toLowerCase()`

Answer (score 3):

The reason your code does not work is because you are not accessing the properties right and trying to match a whole object. `x.includes('A')` is doing a comparison with the whole object that is `x`.

If you just want to filter the objects in an array based on some specific property in them here's how you can do it.

Sample:

`let data = [{id: 1, type: "Pizza"}, {id: 1, type: "Taco"}, {id: 1, type: "Pasta"}, {id: 1, type: "Sandwich"}, {id: 1, type: "Pumpkin Pie"}]`

Process:

`data.filter(x => x.type.toLowerCase().includes('pizza'))`

Output:

`[{id: 1, type: Pizza}]`

or in your case if you want to just sort by the first letter, you can do:

`data.filter(x => x.type.toLowerCase().startsWith('p'))`

Returns:
[ {id: 1, type: "Pizza"},{id: 1, type: "Pasta"}, {id: 1, type: "Pumpkin Pie"} ]`

Comment: `contains()` does not isolate the first character as OP is asking

Comment: Oh, sorry, I wanted to use `includes()`. :)

Comment: This solution works with the example array you have given but for some reason it is giving me error (undefined is not an object (evaluating 'x.CRS_SUBJ_CD.toLowerCase')). Where CRS_SUBJ_CD is type from example code.

Comment: Are you calling `toLowerCase()` with the brackets?

Comment: yes, to be exact this is what I am doing:

let temp1 = temp.filter(x => x.CRS_SUBJ_CD.toLowerCase().startsWith('a'));

Comment: What I can guess by this is that the array you are running this on doesn't have objects. Can you please share what data you are using exactly? You can substitue any values. But I would like to take a look a the data.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215442/discussion-between-danyal-and-shalin-patel).

Comment: Hey btw I figured out what was causing such error. So basically I was importing csv file and setting all the data from the csv file to a state that I declared. But when declaring that state in constructor I had made extra objects in that array which made the data get confusing and break.